# nested id for `store.find` in js-data-firebase adapter

Tags: javascript, firebase, jsdata

I am trying to write a nested query, that I think can look like this:

```
store.find('logs/by_date', '2016-11-02/user%40example,com')
     .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Where the `ID` is not just an `ID`, but a nested location in Firebase. Is this possible with `js-data`?

When I try to run the query above I get the error:

> [Error: [Mapper#createRecord:props] expected: array or object, found: string http://www.js-data.io/v3.0/docs/errors#400] }

Based on the documentation at http://api.js-data.io/js-data-firebase/3.0.0-beta.2/Adapter.html#find__anchor - the ID can be a string/number

I am using node.js and my setup for the store is as follows:

```
store.defineMapper('logs/by_date');
```

I can't really setup a mapper for each date, so how do I achieve this?

My data is structed in firebase as

```
{
  logs : {
    by_date : {
      '2016-11-02' : {
        'user%40example,com' : [
          { msg: "log error 1" },
          { msg: "log error 2" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. What you have looks like it should work. Can you perhaps provide more example data and the method calls you'd like to make?

Comment: interesting, thanks @jdobry I think it may be something to do with the fact that in my example I am using an email as a key.  See updated question. I also pasted the error

Comment: The issue seems to be including this in the search `user%40example,com`

Comment: @jdobry in other words, how could I get the array stored under `user%40example,com`? In firebase this would be done by `firebase.child('/logs/by_date/2016-11-02/user%40example,com')` - What would both the `defineMapper` and `find` look like?